# std::pair analogous in cocoa or foundation kit?

Tags: objective-c, macos, cocoa

I am looking for std::pair analogous in cocoa or foundation kit?

I want just want to pair up two values and use it. If I can use std::pair, it is no longer objective c object and thus I cannot add it to NSMutableArray object.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There’s nothing like that in the standard library, you’ll have to write your own if you feel it’s worth it.

Comment: If you decide to do write your own, you could subclass `NSProxy`.